# bat file that turns off ethernet port and then turns it on - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Is there any way to make a bat file that can turn off Ethernet port and then turn it on afterwards?

I'm working on a project where this is needed every time I turn on the computer and my experience with this is quite limited!

The setting called "Disable" under ethernet as seen here.
[image: The setting called "Disable" under ethernet as seen here.]

Comment: I would look into why you need to do this. I figure the reason why this happens is because you have wifi connected too. I bet if you disconnect from wifi, the problem goes away magically.

Comment: You may want to check out this link on [enabling/disabling Ethernet on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-or-disable-wi-fi-and-ethernet-network-adapters-windows-10) (including via command line). Note that this process typically requires elevation (running as Admin), so you may need to wrap your batch file in a VBScript (`.vbs`) file.

Comment: There are a number of links on Google covering this topic, but [this one](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_elevation.php) covers the basics. An old but fairly easy to use script (assuming you need a starting point) from Microsoft is [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/cc162321(v=msdn.10)).

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```bat
@echo off
netsh interface set interface "Ethernet" disable
timeout /t 2
netsh interface set interface "Ethernet" enable
```

For further details, see [Netsh Command Syntax, Contexts, and Formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-contexts).